# Undefined Variable in Matlab

Tags: oop, matlab

The Following is the basic skeleton for my MATLAB program. Each box is a class definition.

Scroll down for the error.
[image]
**Note:** 1. Each Class has a custom constructor

---

***The Error***

```
Undefined function or variable 'Troom'.

Error in ==> wall>wall.wall at 31
        function o = wall(Tr)

Error in ==> mainfile at 5
        w1 = wall();
```

This comes when I create an object of Class wall from another file "mainfile"

---

***Question***

1. Why is this happening?
2. Am I getting wrong in the concepts of OOP for Matlab specific?
3. How do I resolve this?

Thanks in Advance!

---

PS: ***Code***

```
function o = wall()
        Tr = o.Troom*2;
        o.N = round(1/o.dx) + 1;
        o.T = Tr * ones(o.N,1);
        o.Tinf = Tr;
        o.update_properties();
    end
```

---

***Code 2***

```
classdef wall
properties
    dx = 0.01;
    dt = 0.4;
    L = 0.16;
    N;
    tlimit = 1505.2;
    sbc = 5.670400e-8 % The Stefan-Boltzmann Constant

    a;
    hi; % Surface Conductivity of Inner Surface
    bi;
    ho; % Surface Conductivity of Outer Surface
    bo;
    lamb;

    Troom = 298; % Room Temperature (K)
    Tinf;
    T;

    room = compartment();
    conc = concrete();
    fire = fireProperties(Troom);

end
```

Comment: Actual code would be helpful, it's impossible to say what's happening from what you've given us.

Comment: I have put the constructor code, where the problem is occurring. :)
Hope it helps. The other classes have long code that would perhaps be irrelevant here.

Comment: I am myself confused as to why this is happening.
coz. It is not showing so for other variables.

Comment: It might also help to see the class's `properties` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
room = compartment();
conc = concrete();
fire = fireProperties(Troom);
```

Yeah, there's your problem right there. Troom can't be used in the context of the `properties` block. Either put the constant in for Troom or move these into the constructor where they belong.

Comment: Done! Great! Thanks a lot!
One more question: The OOP docs on Mathworks seem long winded and confusing. Is there a better treatment for matlab OOP than on mathworks?

Comment: You should at least *consider* using Python+numpy+scipy if you are going to do OOP for scientific computing. Python is much better suited for OOP than Matlab, IMO.

Comment: kk. will look into that. Thnx! :)